# Calculating an order total in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm fairly new to rails and i'm trying to calculate an order total without much luck so far. I do not have a basket or cart model, rather the items are held in a basket session. I want to show the total price in the view from products in the basket before an order is created.

I have an Order model, a Product model and an Order_Product model.

In my Order model, i have the following relationships:

```
has_many :order_products
has_many :products, through: :order_products
```

In my Product model, i have the following relationships:

```
has_many :order_products
has_many :orders, through: :order_products
```

In my Order_Product model, i have the following relationships:

```
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
```

In my Order model i have the following method:

```
def total
    products.sum(&:price)
end
```

And in the view i have:

```
<%= @order.total%>
```

I have a Basket controller with the following:

```
def create


    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])

    basket.add(product.id)

    flash[:success] = "Product added to basket"

    redirect_to product_path(product)

end
```

And an Order controller with this:

```
def new

@order = Order.new

    basket.each do |item_id|
        @order.order_products.build(product: Product.find(item_id))
    end

end
```

Here is the basket session in my application controller:

```
def basket
session[:basket] ||= Set.new
end
```

No errors are thrown out but the total rendered in the view is '0' despite there being items in the order. Can anyone lend a hand as i don't know what to do?

Many Thanks

Comment: Did you try in Rails console ? If not first try there, to debug..

Comment: I'm not sure how to debug in the console but when i used the debug method in the view all it gave was this "--- 0
..." It just added dashes and dots before and after the zero.

Comment: Ok.. just in your project root directory.. type `rails c`...Try like `Order.all`.. Then `Order.first.products.sum(&:price)` etc,,, This is how you should first debug the code...

Comment: what is type of the attribute price?

Comment: Okay.. because you are in development mode ( while you start console as **rails c**).. may be your `products` table is empty.. What is the output of `Product.all.size` ?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products"
=> 6

Comment: Sorry check the `orders` tables... :) the error you got, clearly saying, the `orders` table is empty..

Comment: I'm able to switch out the price attribute for any attribute (color, size etc) and it still outputs "0" in the view.                   There aren't any orders in the 'orders' table, all the products are still in the basket at this point...so i must sum them from within the basket...but how

Comment: Humm... got it. Then method `total` should go to your model `Basket`.. Not in `Order`.

Comment: I don't have a basket model though...the basket items are held in a session

Comment: Humm.. you messed all.. Ok.. then how are you holding the items count.. ?

Comment: I've put the parts of the Order controller and Application Controller that relate to the basket in the original question. Does that help?

Comment: @James I believe you want to show the total price in your views from products in the basket before an order is created right?

Comment: yes that's exactly right!..

Comment: Create a helper method, which when called check prices of products in your basket and sums them up. This way you won't have to make many changes.

Comment: Cool...so i've been trying to do that but i really don't know how to go about it. I'm concerned that this post has too many comments, would you mind helping me out over email or something? Thanks

Comment: give me your Skype id and we can chat there

Comment: there are also a [chat rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) here.

Comment: James I noticed you were in my `ROR` chatroom and I tried to communicate but later realized that you didn't have enough reps to chat. Let me know what you think of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *No errors are thrown out but the total rendered in the view is '0' despite there being items in the order.*

The selected `products` are in the `basket`(stored in session) and not yet associated with the `order`. So, the total is rendered as `0`.

Grasping the threads from your comments. 
As per your reply on Babar's comment:

> *Babar: I believe you want to show the total price in your views from products in the basket before an order is created right? James: yes
>   that's exactly right!.*

In order to show the total price in your views for products in the basket, what you can do is add a helper method in `app/helpers/products_helper.rb` file. This way the method would be automatically available across all the views present under `app/views/products` directory.

```
module ProductsHelper
  def basket_total
    Product.where(id: basket.to_a).sum(:price)
  end
end
```

Also, in future if you are planning on displaying a `mini-basket` within header across all pages in your entire site then it would be best to move the helper method in `ApplicationHelper` module (`app/helpers/application_helper.rb`) so it would automatically be available across all the views in your application.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def basket_total
    Product.where(id: basket.to_a).sum(:price)
  end
end
```

Next, it would be good to move `basket` method in `ApplicationHelper` so they would be accessible by `basket_total` as well as your views.

So, your updated `ApplicationHelper` should look like:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def basket_total
    Product.where(id: basket.to_a).sum(:price)
  end

  def basket
    session[:basket] ||= Set.new
  end

end
```

In order to make methods in `ApplicationHelper` available in all controllers, you would need to update `ApplicationController` (`app/controllers/application_controller.rb`) as below:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include ApplicationHelper  ## Add this
  ## ...
end
```

And finally, to access the `basket_total` method in view, use

```
<%= basket_total %>
```

Comment: if i do all of the above as you've explained will the basket_total method also be available in my Order model?

Comment: `basket_total` will only be available in all the Controllers(OrdersController, ProductsController, BasketsController, etc.) and all the views in the application but not in models.

Answer (score 1):

## Kirti's answer is better use that

Creating a helper method resolved the issue, the code was:

```
def total
    price=Product.find(session[:basket].to_a).collect{|product| product.price}.sum
end
```

Comment: +1 For your efforts and going extra mile to help newbies. I wish I knew the you guyz skype id's I could have joined there.

Comment: Thanks a ton, appreciate it a lot